# delete subgraph from graph

Tags: python, igraph

What is the best way of removing a subgraph h from g?

```
# construct g (every vertex has 'name')
# construct h from g (subset of g, that is, 
# 'name' of each vertex is taken from a vertex in g, vertices IDs will be different)
for i in xrange(0, h.vcount()):
  for j in xrange(0, g.vcount()):
    if h.vs[i]['name'] == g.vs[j]['name']:
      g.delete_vertices(j)
```

I'm getting index out of range with this.

Comment: Instead of "suppose I have..." you should post the code you *do* have. You will get much better answers without speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably the most efficient:

```
names_to_remove = set(h.vs["name"])
vs_to_keep = g.vs.select(name_notin=names_to_remove)
g.induced_subgraph(vs_to_keep)
```

The idea here is that first you collect all the vertices in `g` that are *not* in the set to be deleted, and then create the induced subgraph for these vertices.

Comment: Thank you! so if I do "g = g.induced_subgraph(vs_to_keep)" the following line, there should be no problem in terms of shallow copy? Meaning, g will become g - h?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

1. Make a [`copy()`](https://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.GraphBase-class.html) of the graph
2. Apply a [`select()` operation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html#select) on the copied graph's vertex set and `del` (delete) any nodes that meet the criteria
3. Repeat a [`select()`](https://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.EdgeSeq-class.html) and `del` for the copy's edge set, if necessary

Comment: Maybe it is better to delete the edges first, and then the vertices. That also deletes all incident edges.

Comment: can you post an example?